# Best practice to compare lists and extract some data

Tags: numpy, diff, python-3.7

I have an old emails list that should be updated to a new emails list .

I need the **most efficient way** to compare them and select emails deleted from the old list.

the emails list is stored in a DB, so I can get emails ids (emails are unique).

Code I use:

```
old_ids_list = [1, 2, 3]
new_ids_list = [1, 2]
old_emails_list = ['toto@gmail.com', 'lolo@gmail.com', 'momo@gmail.com']
new_emails_list = ['toto@gmail.com', 'lolo@gmail.com',]

if len(old_ids_list) == len(new_ids_list) & len(set(old_ids_list) & set(new_ids_list)) == len(old_ids_list):
    pass
else:
    deleted = numpy.setdiff1d(old_emails_list, new_emails_list, assume_unique=False)
```

Is it a good practice? or it's better to use a `for loop` ? And why?

Comment: what are `old` and `new` exactly?

Comment: Thank you for you interest, I'll update my question

Comment: So, they are email addresses... strings or bytes, I guess. The code seems invalid, though.

Comment: Very good remark. In fact I compare Ids and not emails

Comment: Are you not contemplating added emails because this can never happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in the `if` condition you are already doing the hard work, so there is not much need for testing beforehand.
Secondly, it is not clear how what is your starting point, if it is IDs or emails or either, and your end points.

But it seems that the cleanest approach would be to use `set` all the way.

I assume you are fine with IDs (but the very same code would work for email addresses):

```
n = 3
a = set(range(1, n))  # *old* items
b = set(range(n - 1))  # *new* items


c = a - b  # items present in b but not in a (added)
# {0}
d = b - a  # items present in a but not in b (deleted)
# {2}
```

---

Now, let us assume that the starting point is two `list` (again IDs or email is irrelevant, I'll just assume IDs for simplicity), and let us assume that you want to know both the added and the deleted items. There are a couple of possible approaches:

```
def diffs_set(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    return a - b, b - a
```

```
def diffs_loop(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    return [x for x in a if x in b], [x for x in b if x in a]
```

```
def diffs_loop2(a, b):
    return [x for x in a if x in b], [x for x in b if x in a]
```

```
def diffs_np(a, b):
    return np.setdiff1d(a, b, assume_unique=True), np.setdiff1d(b, a, assume_unique=True)
```

whose timings come out as following for some input sizes:

```
funcs = diffs_set, diffs_loop, diffs_loop2, diffs_np
for n in (10, 100, 1000, 10000):
    print(n)
    old_items = list(range(1, n))
    new_items = list(range(n - 1))
    for func in funcs:
        print(func.__name__)
        %timeit func(old_items, new_items)
    print()
# 10
# diffs_set
# The slowest run took 4.52 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 914 ns per loop
# diffs_loop
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.97 µs per loop
# diffs_loop2
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.09 µs per loop
# diffs_np
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 65.6 µs per loop

# 100
# diffs_set
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.23 µs per loop
# diffs_loop
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 13.6 µs per loop
# diffs_loop2
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 116 µs per loop
# diffs_np
# The slowest run took 5.74 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 65.9 µs per loop

# 1000
# diffs_set
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 57.7 µs per loop
# diffs_loop
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop
# diffs_loop2
# 100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop
# diffs_np
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 374 µs per loop

# 10000
# diffs_set
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 818 µs per loop
# diffs_loop
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 ms per loop
# diffs_loop2
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.06 s per loop
# diffs_np
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.5 ms per loop
```

The most important remark is that by using sets one obtains the fastest and cleanest approach.
It is to note that `set`s are useful even for the `list` comprehension, because the `if` condition gets to be `O(1)` (leading to overall `O(n)`) instead of `O(n)` (leading to overall `O(n²)`).
Because the most expensive operation is to actually build the `set` at the start, it may be possible that the list comprehension gets competitive against using only sets if only `a - b` or `b - a` are needed, because then only one `set()` call is necessary.
On the contrary, the NumPy-based approach is not competitive here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension. As you said that the emails are unique themselves, I am not sure what you want to do with the ids and we don't need to convert to sets (correct me if I got you wrong).

```
deleted = [email for email in old_emails_list if email not in new_emails_list]
```

The pros of this approach, imho, are that it is well-readable and that no external package is required.

**edit**
To check whether the new list differs from the old list, there are two szenarios:
a) If the new list is known to be a sublist of the old list, just check whether there is any element in `deleted` as computed above.
b) If there might be new emails in the new list, check whether `deleted` contains any emails and if it doesn't, additionally check whether `len(new_emails_list)==len(old_emails_list)`.

Comment: I need to know if the list has been changed. And then -1) select deleted emails to inform them -2)send another different mail to the new list.

Comment: For the check whether they differ see my edit. The points 1) and 2) are not addressed in your question, are they? What exactly is your question there regarding the lists of emails?

Comment: note that the `in` operator for a `list` is `O(n)` while for sets is `O(1)`. For more then a few comparisons it is beneficial to use convert a set and then use `in` (if memory allows), e.g.`new_emails_set = set(new_emails_list); deleted = [email for email in old_emails_list if email not in new_emails_set]`